# extraneous characters in UIPickerView output to UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that I use to list data from a CoreData Entity. The data output always contains the entity's attribute name and extraneous characters that I assume are CoreData formatting; for example the following is `NSLog` output I get looks like:

```
NSLog(@"%@",roomNames);

output:
(
        {
        roomName = "Living Room";
    }
)
```

The following is the code I use to extract the data from the picker view:

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[roomNames objectAtIndex:row]];
    roomTxt.text = resultString;

}
```

I cannot determine where the characters come from or how to remove them from the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update your question with the `NSLog` statement so we know what you are logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this line.

```
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[roomNames objectAtIndex:row]];
```

`%@` calls the object's descriptionWithLocale: or description: method. It wasn't intended to be used to get the string value of an object, but a description in string form. Looks like it's just logging the name/key pairs for all attributes.

> The description method is implemented by NSObject to return the class and memory address of the object, but many Cocoa and Cocoa Touch
>   classes override it to provide more useful information.
>   (from [Working With Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html))

You need the attribute's value. What type of object is being pulled from roomNames?

Comment: I am just interested in the string value "Living Room" in this case.

Comment: @soundChaser I'm guessing your array "roomNames" includes NSManagedObjects? Since you mentioned you're using Core Data and the log is logging attribute names + values. In which  case you just use [[roomNames objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey: @"roomName"].

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. It's so obvious now that you pointed it out. I kept getting wrapped around the axel. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @soundChaser No problem, we all make these sorts of mistakes occasionally.